# Within the database, where is the flag which says that a user has Super Admin rights?

Tags: multisite, database, mysql, user-roles

I have an user in a Wordpress Multisite installation and have access to the Mysql database, I would like to give myself super-admin rights to access the wp-admin/network page. Where can I do it on Mysql?

I looked the database and I think the wp_usersmeta table is the one, but I have no idea how Wordpress manages the roles within the database.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually stored in the {prefix}sitemeta table. The meta key is site_admins, and it's a serialized PHP array of usernames.

Comment: Thanks! I added my username to that array and it worked.